SSH Unable to negotiate: no matching host key type found
I have an issue where older clients aren't able to connect to current (v8.x) versions of openssh server. I'm familiar with adding ssh-rsa,ssh-dss to the list of available key types but that doesn't seem to work for this issue.
One of our vendors is the client and there's no option of passing flags. When they try and connect, I get the following:
Apr 16 20:57:13 server sshd[70429]: Unable to negotiate with 10.0.3.39 port 49100: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]

I've added the following to /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/10-test.conf
KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

As well as having no '=' but it has no effect. Here's the debug output:
[centos@ip-10-0-3-39 ~]$ ssh -vv -i test test@10.0.3.225
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.3.225 [10.0.3.225] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file test type -1
debug1: identity file test-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
no hostkey alg

Does anyone have any ideas here as I'm at a loss.
Thanks!

Does your sshd_config Include the .d/* files? (Not all do, and it's not default.) Does sshd_config, or .d/*, if used contain any HostKey settings, and do they include RSA and/or DSA, or does it leave the defaults (which in 8.7 does not include DSA)? Do the configured or defaulted RSA and/or DSA files exist and have correct permissions and contain valid readable keys?

You do know that this is CentOS 6, which has no security support, and it also does not support any secure signature algorithms (all of them use SHA-1, which is absolutely insecure).  Are you sure you want such an insecure system to log into your machine?

First try on CLI, with various options

ssh -vv -A -t -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss test@10.0.3.225

then update the ssh_config file accordingly
